# Finding the appropriate version of xcode for Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode

from the whole list of versions in https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ , how can I know which ones are compatible with my OS X version?
I have 10.10.5 installed and know that xcode 7 won't work (so installing from the AppStore is out of the question).
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of different versions along with the operating system versions that they will work with:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Version_comparison_table